# Long table (longtabu) and font style issues

Tags: tables, fonts, longtable

I use the `longtabu` environment for my tables to span it across several pages. This works great, however, I always change the font size and type as you will see in my example. This worked also very well until I tried to combine long tables and the new font style. I always put the font definitions within the `table` but outside the `tabu` environment as latex always throws an error when it is inside the `tabu` environment. So, I guess, you already see my problem. The `longtabu` environment does not work within a `table` environment but I cannot put my font definitions within the `longtabu` environment. Is there a way around it? Can I create a box or so around the `longtabu`? The problem is when I do not put the font definitions within the `table` environment, all the text that comes after that table gets the same font. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,DIV=12,a4paper,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{\fontfamily{#1} \fontseries{#2} \fontshape{#3} \selectfont}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\changefont{phv}{m}{n} % Change font to Helvetica

\fontsize{6}{9} \selectfont{ % Change font size and line spacing to 6 and 9 respectively

\begin{longtabu}{ll}

Longtable & Longtable \\
Longtable & Longtable \\
Longtable & Longtable \\
Longtable & Longtable \\
Longtable & Longtable \\

\end{longtabu}

}

\caption{This is a caption}

\end{table}

%% New example code
{

\changefont{phv}{m}{n}

\fontsize{6}{9} \selectfont

\begin{longtabu}{ll}

\toprule

\rowfont{\bfseries\itshape}

Longtable & Longtable \\
Longtable & Longtable \\
Longtable & Longtable \\
Longtable & Longtable \\
Longtable & Longtable \\

\bottomrule

\end{longtabu}

}

This is text after the long table and shoud be in standard latex format again. Apparently, it is not as you can see from
the baseline stretch which seems not to be 1.2. However, the font type seems to be ok.

\end{document}
```

Comment: It should work if you leave out the `table` environment and just move the `{` which is after `\selectfont` before `\changefont`.

Comment: Right, I just swapped the two lines \changefont and \fontsize and indeed the font after the table is then times new roman again. However, the font size is still set to 6 and 9. What I could do is to reapply the \fontsize command with \selection{} after the table to set it back to normal font size. The problem is that the two parameters for font size and line spacing seem not to correspond with the standard latex font. so \fontsize{10}{1.2} does not restore to the original font type. In the preamble I specified: \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}. So I don't know how to set the paramters...

Comment: Swapping the lines is not enough, **the `{` is in the wrong place**. You need `{\changefont{phv}{m}{n}\fontsize{6}{9} \selectfont`. `\selectfont` is just a switching command, it doesn't take an argument.

Comment: Thanks for your comment stephan. I added another example above as I understood it from your explanation. However, it still doesn't quite work. The baselinestretch is still not correct. The font type itself seems to be ok but it's just a guess too :) Sorry, but to get this working is very important for me. I spent so much time on it already and I need to continue with the actual writing as soon as possible...

Comment: The example is ok. Are you sure that you didn't compile a different document where a spurious `\fontsize{6}{9}` were still active at the end?

Comment: Oh dear. Ok the problem is solved. I forgot to add the \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2} into my simple example and apparently that was the problem of why the baseline stretch was set to latex standard. Thanks everyone for the useful comments. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `longtabu` in a `table` environment doesn't make sense, because `table` cannot be split across pages. It's not very clear what you want to achieve. However, defining a new environment could be the solution.

```
\documentclass[10pt,DIV=12,a4paper,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\linespread{1.2}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{\usefont{\f@encoding}{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\patchcmd{\LT@makecaption}{\hss}{\hss\normalfont\normalsize}{}{}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{myfont}[6][1]
  {\par\linespread{#1}\fontsize{#5}{#6}\changefont{#2}{#3}{#4}}
  {\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{myfont}{phv}{m}{n}{6}{9} % Change font to Helvetica
\begin{longtabu}{ll}

Longtable & Longtable \\
Longtable & Longtable \\
Longtable & Longtable \\
Longtable & Longtable \\
Longtable & Longtable \\
\caption{This is a caption}
\end{longtabu}
\end{myfont}

This is text after the long table and shoud be in standard latex format again. Apparently, 
it is not as you can see from the baseline stretch which seems not to be 1.2. However, the 
font type seems to be ok.

\end{document}
```

Notice the use of `\linespread{1.2}` rather than `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}`. However it's preferable to use the `setspace` package and its `\setstretch{1.2}` command.

I've redefined your `\changefont` command in a possibly clearer way using the standard `\usefont` command. In `\f@encoding` the current encoding is stored.

The `myfont` environment can be used anywhere. It has five mandatory arguments: family, series, shape, size and baselineskip and an initial optional argument, the baseline stretch (default 1).

I've also patched the `\caption` command inside a `longtable` (or `longtabu` which uses the same) so that it's typeset in normal font and size.

[image]

Comment: Hi egreg, thanks a lot for this solution. There are 2 things I want to ask you. 1) what's the difference between \linespread and setstretch and why is it better than the baselinestretch command I used? When I change \linespread to \setstretch, in your code, can I simpl replace \par\linespread{#1} with \par\setstretch{#1}? 2) I am wondering how I can set the initial optional argument (the baselinestretch) to 1.2? Apparently, the line spread{1.2} sets it to 1.2 but this is overwritten by your code and set back to one within the \begin{my font} environment. I can I set this optional param to 1.2?

Comment: @Josh If you use `setspace`, just replace `\linespread` with `\setstretch`. It's preferable because it does some more things which help in limiting the awful result of increasing the interline space so much. If you replace `[6][1]` in the definition of `myfont` with `[6][1.2]` you'll have that the default value of the optional argument is 1.2

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is fantastic! I need to incorporate this now into my actual latex environment but everything seems to work so far. I let you know after I migrated that if it works or not. Thumbs crossed but I think it will. In case I have some troubles I hope I can come back to you. Sorry, just one more thing for now. Is the toolbox package you used needed to create this new myfont function?

Comment: Hi egreg, I just realized that whenever I use caption now that the baseline stretch is not 1.2 but just 1. The font apparently as we can see from your image is the standard latex font but since the caption is very short I did not realize that the line space is now 1 and not 1.2 anylonger. I guess this is because you  patched the caption in your code. I have no idea how to changes this back unfortunately.

Comment: One of the workings of `setspace` is to reduce the interline space to normal in some situations. So large a baseline skip is, in my opinion awful; a caption with enlarged baseline skip is even more awful.

Comment: Pheeww, Ok, using \linespread{1.2} rather than \setstretch{1.2} changes the caption back to how I like it with 1.2 as the stretch. Sorting this out took a bit longer now and I still need to change the environment for some other tables. Let's hope it works now ;-) thanks again for your comment. It is really appreciated. Especially for people like me who are lost editing or changing code like you have written.